# How can I use one module across project files

Tags: python, package, modularity

Having the current file structure:

```
root
|
|_init.py
|
|_utils
| __functions.py
| __init.py
|
|_folder1
| __folder1.2
|  ___working_file.py
|  ___init.py`
```

How can I use the module `functions.py` within the module `workin_file.py` without calling

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path_of_functions.py')
```

within `working_file.py`?

Is there any way to make it more generic? I am looking to deploy the project on a server and I don´t want to change the file path within `sys.path.append(...)` every time. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the .py file you your site-packages folder (for me `C:\Users\[username]\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`). This will make you able to globally import it to Python.

Comment: Thank you very much, this sounds promising! I´m also looking forward to ship this project to a customer, is there a way to handle this within the code? Because I´m expecting my customer to not have the same file structure.

Comment: the path of your site-packages folder depends on how you're using Python. For me it's through Anaconda distribution, but it may differ from computer to computer, so I'm afraid it would take some manual location of the site-packages folder.

Somebody else can probably give you a more versatile solution in that case : )

Comment: If the customer will not have the same file structure, then you will have to search where is that file that you want add to sys.path, one python module that is very good for this is os.walk, read it right here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm